# Rank base on date repeating elements

Tags: pyspark

I have a list of items with a date. I want to create a rank on my data by level. I try with rank and dense_rank, but the date seams to always interfer in the leveling of my data.

Here the data:

```
df.show()

+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|ID        |VAL       |TORF      |DT        |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|1         |2         |true      |2020-01-04|
|1         |2         |true      |2020-01-05|
|1         |2         |false     |2020-01-06|
|1         |2         |false     |2020-01-07|
|1         |2         |true      |2020-01-08|
|1         |2         |false     |2020-01-09|
|1         |2         |true      |2020-01-10|
|2         |2         |true      |2020-01-04|
|2         |2         |true      |2020-01-05|
|2         |2         |false     |2020-01-06|
|2         |2         |false     |2020-01-07|
|2         |2         |true      |2020-01-08|
|2         |2         |false     |2020-01-09|
|2         |2         |true      |2020-01-10|
+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

Here the column I would like to add to the dataframe:

```
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|ID        |VAL       |TORF      |DT        |LEVEL     |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|1         |2         |true      |2020-01-04|1         |
|1         |2         |true      |2020-01-05|1         |
|1         |2         |false     |2020-01-06|2         |
|1         |2         |false     |2020-01-07|2         |
|1         |2         |true      |2020-01-08|3         |
|1         |2         |false     |2020-01-09|4         |
|1         |2         |true      |2020-01-10|5         |
|2         |2         |true      |2020-01-04|1         |
|2         |2         |true      |2020-01-05|1         |
|2         |2         |false     |2020-01-06|2         |
|2         |2         |false     |2020-01-07|2         |
|2         |2         |true      |2020-01-08|3         |
|2         |2         |false     |2020-01-09|4         |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: could you elaborate on how you are ranking and add it in the question?  it _looks_ like "per `ID`, order by `DT` and change increment level when `TORF` flips." but I am not sure if that is what you want.

Comment: @emma: Yes this is what I want to do. Increment level when TORF flips and restart the level when either ID or VAL change.

Comment: could you add that description in the question so that everyone else can find it easily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first create a flag that is `true` when you want to increment the level and `false` when it is not.

That is

- When a row is the first row per group

  ```
  w = Window.partitionBy('ID', 'VAL').orderBy('DT')

  F.lag('TORF').over(w).isNull()
  ```
- When the `TORF` is different from the last `TORF` in the same group.

  ```
  F.col('TORF') != F.lag('TORF').over(w)
  ```

Once you create this flag, you can cumsum it.

Final code.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

w = Window.partitionBy('ID', 'VAL').orderBy('DT')

df = (df.withColumn('LEVEL', F.lag('TORF').over(w).isNull() 
                             | (F.col('TORF') != F.lag('TORF').over(w)))
      .withColumn('LEVEL', F.sum(F.col('LEVEL').cast('int')).over(w)))
```